# python screen-scraping to click a particular image in a html5 image map

Tags: python, html, image-processing, screen-scraping

In a html5 page using [image map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map), I would like to use python (or Perl, Ruby, C) to crawl it to find a particular image (those are separated by a transparency area) in another one and click it when this image is found. The image are the same all the times. What is the best way to achieve this ?

**Edit**: for french readers, the trick is implemented, see http://www.sputnick-area.net/?p=572

Comment: I mean I want to simulate a click in the "image map"

Comment: That would be "clicking" a `<a>` tag. Then what? You want to fetch the URL it's referring? Save it to disk? Process/parse it?

Comment: There's no "a" tag, that would be obvious ! There's html5 area tags. The trick is to process the image randomly generated to find the position of a sub-image inside the bigger one. When I have the position (x,y) I would like to simulate clicking on a sub-image.

Comment: OK, `<area>` tag, no `<a>` (which BTW not that different). After reading your question 4th (or 5th) time, now I think I understand what you want. This has more to do with image processing, than html. It would be better to if you clarify question with possible examples of images (big and small).

Comment: I need to recognize position of the "6" by example in this image http://ompldr.org/vYXZ4dg (sorry for my post, I'm French, I do my best)

Comment: Ah, I see. You want to automate a login procedure or sorts. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/) might be a perfect for this. It is based on Jython, thus can be extended with Python or Java tools.

> Sikuli is a visual technology to automate and test graphical user
>   interfaces (GUI) using images (screenshots). Sikuli includes Sikuli
>   Script, a visual scripting API for Jython, and Sikuli IDE, an
>   integrated development environment for writing visual scripts with
>   screenshots easily.

**Edit**

If the image is that well defined as in your example, that can be easily matched without much image processing. Here I used matplotlib (small image must be exact cropped version of large image).

Target image (65x173):

[image]

Image to be matched (29x29):

[image]

```
In [48]: import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

In [49]: target = pl.imread("r.png")

In [50]: match = pl.imread("xx.png")

In [51]: target.shape
Out[51]: (65, 173, 4)

In [52]: match.shape
Out[52]: (29, 29, 4)

In [53]: for y in range(2):
   ....:     for x in range(5):
   ....:         sub_x = 36*x
   ....:         sub_y = 36*y
   ....:         sub_target = target[sub_y:sub_y+29,sub_x:sub_x+29,:]
   ....:         if (match == sub_target).all():
   ....:             print "Match found between (%d,%d) and (%d,%d)" % (sub_x,sub_y,sub_x+29,sub_y+29)
   ....:
Match found between (72,0) and (101,29)
```

Comment: I know Sikuli, sure it's a good and interesting way to do the trick, but I would like to do this in the background if possible by downloading the image file and processing it with by example with the following python 2 module https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Xpresser
Hope that's possible =)

Comment: @sputnick: Well, if your image is that fixed, you might do it easily. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks ! The whole image is not that fixed, the images numbers are randomly ordered (those are all the times the sames). Is there still any chance to do it successfully with matplotlib ?

Comment: @sputnick: That's interesting. The sub-images are not same in those two. The white numbers are not placed same over the blue background. For example the "6" I used is off by 1px in the second image. Well, that is not good :).

Comment: Ok, interesting yes. Is there another python approach to search the numbers (instead of the squares) with a tolerance ? (sikuli do that)

Answer (score 0):

I take it the images are always the same so the 6 is at the same offset and covered by the same  tag. Clicking the image at this point will follow the URL defined in the  href attribute. So follow that link.